# Before insert trigger behavior in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created a table with some data in it, and a trigger like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS verifica_cpf;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER verifica_cpf
    BEFORE INSERT ON `usuario` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE  cpf = new.cpf) > 1 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'CPF EXISTENTE!';            
        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Basically it checks for duplicate 'cpf' values before inserts.

Let's say that in my table, there's one entry with this cpf value: 873.255.218-12

If i try to insert another entry with the same cpf value, the trigger won't work. But if i insert it again, it will.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by changing the `1` to `0`:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS verifica_cpf;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER verifica_cpf
    BEFORE INSERT ON `usuario` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE  cpf = new.cpf) > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'CPF EXISTENTE!';            
        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Or by using the more efficient `if exists`:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS verifica_cpf;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER verifica_cpf
    BEFORE INSERT ON `usuario` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF exists (SELECT 1 FROM usuario WHERE  cpf = new.cpf) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'CPF EXISTENTE!';            
        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```